# How to put a parameterized sql transaction in a cursor?

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

For a more detailed explanation, I have this scenario.

I know this is the correct way to initiate a cursor:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT NAME FROM namelist;
OPEN cur;
```

But I need it to be like this

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT NAME FROM namelist where nameID in ('1,2,3,4');
OPEN cur;
```

The reason is Is I am passing the numbers (1,2,3,4) on a parameter of my stored procedure

so lets say I have this parameter, which was taken from the system

```
declare @namelist as varchar(20) 
set @namelist = '1,2,3,4'
```

I want the value of the parameter to be used in my `IN` statement

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT NAME FROM namelist where nameID in (@namelist)
OPEN cur;
```

but the only way I know how to do that is by using this method:

```
    exec (SELECT NAME FROM namelist where nameID in ('+@namelist+'))
```

however this method cannot be used like this:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
     exec (SELECT NAME FROM namelist where nameID in ('+@namelist+')
OPEN cur;
```

the is an error that state

```
Incorrect syntax  near exec, expecting'(', SELECT, or WITH
```

So can you guys give me an idea how to use a parameterized statement in a cursor?

Comment: Why are you using a `CURSOR` in the first place? If you want to pass multiple values though, you want a table value parameter; not a delimited list.

Comment: 1) You don't need cursors 2) Use table-valued parameters if you need to pass multiple values.. The problem is the incorrect attempt to pass multiple values in a parameter. You *didn't* post the relevant code but the only way the "workarounds" would work is if `@namelist` was a string. In which case, it contains a *single* string value, not multiple IDs.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you really need a `CURSOR` here, almost every time (I'd go as far as 99% of the time) a `CURSOR` is being used incorrectly and a set based method would be far better.

Anyway, for what you want here, you'll be better off using a table-value parameter. I *assume* this is inside an SP, so you'll have to do something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.IntList AS TABLE (I int);
GO

ALTER YourSP @FirstParam varchar, @NameID dbo.IntList READONLY AS
BEGIN ...

    DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
         SELECT NAME FROM namelist NL JOIN @NameID N ON NL.NameID = N.I;
    ...

END;

GO

DECLARE @NameID dbo.IntList;
INSERT INTO @NameID
VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4);

EXEC YourSP @FirstParam = 'SomeValue', @NameID = @NameID READONLY;
```

If you do want to move to a set based approach here, however, you'd be better off asking a different question. How to pass a list of items (to a `CURSOR`) and how to change a iterative method to a set based method are very different, and unrelated, questions.